# Flowgraph Aptitude question

Tags: algorithms

I recently looked a Flow-Graph question.

Consider 8 boxes with following values

```
Box 1 = 2
Box 2 = 7
Box 3 = 2
Box 4 = 1
Box 5 = 5
Box 6 = 7
Box 7 = 1
Box 8 = 4
```

Now follow the instructions:

1. Put the number from Box 7 into Box 1
2. Add the numbers from Box 1 and Box 2 , and put the result in Box 1
3. Change Instruction 2, Increase the number in Box 2 by 1
4. If the second box number mentioned in instruction 2 is greater than the number in box 8, stop. If not, go to step 2.

What number is in Box 1 now?

Note: When you are told to put a number into a box, it is understood that whatever number was previously in that box has just been erased.

When I tried to solve:

1. b[1] = 1
2. b[1] = 1+7 = 8
3. b[b[2]] = b[7]+1 =b[7]=2
4. b[2] > b[8]
   7 > 4 : true

result: 8

But the solution is 11! how? I got stuck.Am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: I think instruction 3 is unclear. If I read it as "Change Instruction 2 to 'Increase the number in Box 2 by 1' then 4 doesn't make any sense.  I'm not sure how it's intended to be read.

Comment: @AlanShutko: yes! But the question states same. it purposefully confuses us. i guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how I interpret it:

1. *Put the number from Box 7 into Box 1* - fairly straightforward.  The number in box 7 gets set as the number in box 1.
2. *Add the numbers from Box 1 and Box 2 , and put the result in Box 1* - also fairly straightforward.  The sum of boxes 1 and 2 gets assigned to box 1.
3. *Change Instruction 2, Increase the number in Box 2 by 1* - I think quotation marks here would make this clearer -- **Increase the number in "Box 2" by 1.**  This is to say, instruction 2 now reads *"Add the numbers from Box 1 and Box 3 , and put the result in Box 1"*
4. *If the second box number mentioned in instruction 2 is greater than the number in box 8, stop. If not, go to step 2.* - The reason for the strange wording is for the simple fact that the box number mentioned in the 2nd instruction is subject to changes.  We will loop this algorithm for 4 times, where Box 5 will end the loop (since Box 8 holds value 4).

That said, after applying it to this set, you get the following steps:

```
2 7 2 1 5 7 1 4
1 7 2 1 5 7 1 4
8 7 2 1 5 7 1 4
10 7 2 1 5 7 1 4
11 7 2 1 5 7 1 4
```

And if box 1 contains the solution, then it is 11.

The algorithm seems to put the sum of the numbers in each box in the first box. It is certainly a strange way to go about doing an algorithm.  It isn't exactly clear what happens to numbers that are "taken out" of another box if they are swapped, if 0 is placed in its stead, or if the number is copied.  I assumed in this example that the number is simply copied, but the answer to this problem depends on this and it isn't mentioned.

Comment: so the clue here is change the instruction 2. is there any other way to compute this without using brute-force?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  You could consider brute force as a type of algorithm.  This is its own algorithm.  If you mean, how can you obtain this result wthout following the algorithm?  You can't, though you'd have to modify the algorithm so that instruction (change instruction 2) works with most modern programming languages (i.e. using arrays and incrementing index rather than box number).

Answer (score 0):

step|     My solution

1. 1  |      1(new box1)
2. 2  |      1+7 = 8(new box1)
3. 3 | add: BOX1+ (BOX3)=box1  {no execution needed just change the
   instruction}
4. 4   |      3(box3) >  4(number in box 8)  NO(back to step2)
5. 2   |      8+2=10
6. 3   |add: BOX1+ (BOX4)=box1  {no execution needed just change the
   instruction}
7. 4   |      4> 4 :  NO(back to step 2)
8. 2   |      10 + 1 = 11
9. 3   |add: BOX1+ (BOX5)=box1  {no execution needed just change the
   instruction}
10. 4   |     5>4   YES

END of the LOOP.    box 1 = 11